# How do you import a CSV file that has spaces in the path?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am fairly new to powershell, but I want to import a csv file that has a column labeled "SamAccountName", and that column contains a list of AD accounts to be moved to a disabled users OU. The main problem I am having is the file path, (The one in my code is not the real file path obviously) it's throwing an error because of spaces in the file path. How do I go about fixing that without renaming the files? Also if you have any recommendations for my current code feel free to give them to me, I'm always open to feedback.

Also the "AD ACCOUNT NOT FOUND" bit is in there because these are auto generated csv's and if the user doesn't have an account, this is what get put into the column.

```
#DECLARING VARIABLES
$csv = import-csv c:\example\file path\file.csv
$ou = "OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=Users,DC=MHC,DC=LOCAL"
$totalLines = 0
$notFound = 0
$found = 0

#SEARCHES CSV FOR THE SAMACCOUNTNAMES THEN MOVES THE ACCOUNTS
foreach ($c in $csv) {
  $totalLines++
    if ($c.SamAccountName -eq "AD ACCOUNT NOT FOUND!"){
        $notFound++
    } else {
        $c.SamAccountName
        write-host "Moving "$c.SamAccountName"..." -nonewline
        Get-ADUser $c.SamAccountName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $ou | Set-ADObject $c.SamAccountName -replace @{msExchHideFromAddressLists=$true}
    write-host " Done" -foreground green
    $found++
    }
}

#JUST OUTPUTS EVERYTHING THAT IT DID
write-host
write-host "*************************************"
write-host "Process Complete"
write-host $found "Accounts moved" -foreground green
write-host $notFound "Accounts not found" -foreground red
write-host $totalLines "Lines processed" -foreground yellow
```

Comment: so ... enclose the path in quotes? [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you should avoid spaces in files if you can, you can get around it by placing it all in quotation marks. That's how I import all my CSV's with iffy file paths/names.

```
$csv = import-csv "c:\example\file path\file.csv"
```